# Implementing a filter whose function takes an argument

Tags: haskell, filter, functional-programming

I am writing some Haskell which aims to take a list of numbers and filter out any number that isn't triangular.

```
main :: IO()
main = do
    interact tri

tri :: String -> String
tri =   unwords . 
        map show .
        filter (isSquare (\n -> (8*n+1))) . 
        map (read :: String -> Int) . 
        words

isSquare :: (Integral a) => a -> Bool
isSquare n = (round . sqrt $ fromIntegral n) ^ 2 == n
```

This is what I have so far. Where I am having trouble is the filter.

I don't fully understand how I might go about actually *accessing* the value in that anonymous function (or, for that matter, if this is even possible in this manner). I need to test each number using this function in combination with `isSquare` to determine whether the number is triangular. I understand the exercise is purely academic, I'm just trying to learn about function composition and IO mostly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Does the expression `(isSquare (\n -> (8*n+1)))` type-check? Why not?
2. `filter` has the type `(a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`. So its first argument needs to be a function of type `(a -> Bool)`. You are *almost* there with this; what function do you want here, and how can you construct it with what you have? Hint: It's a single-character change.

Comment: I'm close, been playing with `ghci` for a few minutes now to try and work it out but I'm not getting much. Have I made a mistake with the composition? I feel like I need a dollar-sign or a period somewhere.

EDIT: Yeah, put a period between isSquare and the lambda!

Comment: @capncoolio : Yes, that familiar feeling of needing _just_ one more dollar-sign or a period (or maybe it is an `fmap` or `flip` or ...) somewhere in here ... . Jokes apart, you should sit and think _slowly_ about the various **types** involved. That is the key to getting past this stage of uncertainty. Ask yourself what the type of each "thing" in your program is. Even better, ask ghci (`:t thing` gives the type of "thing"). Now ask, for each thing which fails to type-check (where ghci throws an error), *why* it fails. As Euclid said, "There is no royal road to Haskell.".

Comment: You won't do badly if you start with my first question. *Figure out* why `:t (isSquare (\n -> (8*n+1)))` results in an error message. It helps if you look at  the types of each of the two sub-expressions involved in this.

Comment: @G Philip I have to say, the type error it threw at me was about a billion lines long and quite hard to understand. I *kind of* get it, but I'll definitely do some reading. I have a couple of Haskell wizards at my disposal in real life, so I might use them too.

Comment: @capncoolio: It's true that ghci type error messages are scary and need quite some getting used to. But it does point you to the expression which caused the error, and then you can try to manually look at the types of the different sub-expressions involved, and figure out the problem yourself.

Comment: `:t (\n -> (8*n+1))` gives me `(\n -> (8*n+1)) :: Num a => a -> a`, which seems... fine? It gives back an a, and `isSquare` expects one...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75261/discussion-between-g-philip-and-capncoolio).